# Actionscript 3 starling how to drag and only drop if it is over one of many squares

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, starling-framework

I am making a tower defense game for a class of mine. I decided to use starling with Flash and I am having a bit of trouble. Is there any was for me to specify that the towers can only be dropped into place if they are with in the bounds of a specific image/ in a 100px range of a specified center point? I would want to be able to store the points to be able to reference as I will have about 10-20 spots to place the towers. I feel like I might just be over thinking this.
Any help or guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the hitTest method and add some dummies for locate the placing. If your hitTest method returns a dummy object you know that you are on a good place.

see [Starling DisplayObject:hitTest()](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTest%28%29);

Comment: Oh that might be what I am looking for. I will give it a try. Thanks!!